# How many numbers can be added to BlockedNumbers in Android? (guesses welcome)

Tags: android

I've been experimenting today with trying to build a call-blocking app for Android to prevent receiving unwanted robocalls from telemarketers and scammers. After a little tinkering I was able to whip up a very crude proof of concept using a fork of the stock Android Phone application. The crude proof of concept simply allows me to enter a number into an EditText and then add the number to the block list-- nothing special but it's a start.

I estimate that there are likely 500,000 spammer/scammer/telemarketing phone numbers that would need to be added to the BlockedNumbers list in Android to make this work. At first I thought this wouldn't be possible, but after a little back of the envelope math, it looks like 500,000 phone numbers only comes to around 5 megabytes worth of data.

So does anyone have any idea how many phone numbers can be added to BlockedNumbers in Android? Any guesses would be appreciated! And yes I know that I could develop an experiment to test this myself, and I might just do that eventually.

P.S. If anyone happens to stumble upon this in the future trying to build the same thing, here is a link to the modified and "hackable" version of the stock Android Phone application:

https://github.com/dangleon/customdialer

NOTE: The Android application responsible for receiving phone calls doesn't seem to be something you can "hack on." The fork posted above is simply a dialer application, and doesn't handle incoming calls.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it's been 12 days now since I asked my question here on StackOverflow and I didn't receive any answers. However, I'm proud to say that I built an application last night to test how many phone numbers can be added to the BlockedNumbers list in Android. Running my test application I was able to add 500,000 numbers to the BlockedNumbers list, no problem. I'm not sure what the exact upper limit is on how many numbers can be added to this list, but I know for sure that you can add at least 500,000 numbers to BlockedNumbers on a Moto G4 running Android 7.0. I'm not sure if anyone is ever going to stumble upon this post, but if someone does, I hope you've found my post helpful! And if everything goes as planned, maybe you will have heard of the app I'm building: PhreakPhone-- A Crowdsourced Telemarketing Call-Blocker for Android

P.S., This is the first answer I've ever posted on StackOverflow, feels great to have finally contributed to such an awesome site.